# I'm confused by the term 'adjunct' as used in A Student's Introduction to English Grammar (2nd Edition 2022)

Tags: syntax, grammar, clauses, adjuncts

According to the authors of the book, **adjuncts** are divided into two kinds: **modifiers**, which are thoroughly integrated into the syntactic structure of clauses, and **supplements**, which are much more loosely connected to the sentences in which they’re found. In other words, adjunct is an umbrella term to cover **modifiers** **in the NP, VP, AdjP, AdvP, and PP construction**, and **supplements**.

Here is what confuses me: when the authors explain the main dependents in the VP construction, they make a distinction between complements and adjuncts (p.65).

> The dependents of the predicator in the **VP** are of two main kinds:
> **complements** and **adjuncts**.

However, when they explain the main dependants of the other constructions (**NP** (p.83), **AdjP** (p.118), and **AdvP** (p.124), they somehow specifically makes a distinction between complements and modifiers, not between complements and adjuncts.

> Dependents in the structure of the **NP** are of three main types:
> determiners, **complements**, and **modifiers**. (p.83)

> An **AdjP** consists of an adjective as head, alone or accompanied by one
> or more dependents. The dependents may be **complements**, licensed by the
> head, or **modifiers**, less restricted in their occurrence. (p.118)

> The structure of **AdvPs** is similar to that of AdjPs, but somewhat
> simpler. Dependents can again be divided into **complements** and
> **modifiers**. (p.124)

So I'm wondering why VP gets such different treatment? Is there a reason they can't specifically pinpoint whether an adjunct in VP is either modifier or supplement?

**Edit1:** Here is the examples of the adjunct in SIEG 2nd edition, which indicate that 'adjunct' is used to cover **modifiers in the** **NP, VP, AdjP, AdvP and PP** **construction**, and **supplements**; not just **modifiers** **in** **VP, Clauses** and **supplements** as defined in CGEL, SIEG 1 [image: This implies 'adjunct' include modifier in AdjP (ii), AdvP (iii), and PP (iv)]
*This implies 'adjunct' includes modifier in AdjP (ii), AdvP (iii), and PP (iv)* (p. 214)

[image]
*The adjunct in 4-iv is clearly a modifier in the NP [some item in the containing clause] (p. 224)*

**Edit2:** It turns out the above examples are an oversight on the authors' part. They promise to fix it in the next reprint. Please refer to @BillJ comment under this question.

Comment: Supplements are not modifiers. Adjuncts only occur in clause structure, not phrase structure. A complement must be licensed by the head, whereas an adjunct doesn't. In other words, an adjunct cannot be a complement -- they are distinct functions.

Comment: No: it is incorrect to say that an adjunct is an umbrella term to cover modifiers in the NP, VP, AdjP, AdvP construction, and supplements. Adjuncts only occur in clause structure, or as supplements, not phrase structure. In phrase structure, the dependents are either modifiers or complements, the latter being licensed by the head, the former not.

Comment: @BillJ "Adjuncts only occur in clause structure, or as supplements, not phrase structure" That is what I formerly believed. However, on page 214 of the second edition of the book (recently publshed this year), the authors provide the examples of the adjunct that are clearly elements in phrase structures. Please refer to the screenshot in my answer as I cannot post a picture as a comment.

Comment: I'm surprised by what appears to be a major change by the authors when compared to the first edition of SIEG. Previously, modifiers in phrase structure were not called adjuncts, but simply modifiers. I don't have a copy of the 2nd edition. In the first edition, 'Adjunct' is defined as a modifier in clause structure, or a supplement. Can you please look in the Glossary at the back of your book and see what it says for 'Adjunct'. Examples i and v-vii are adjuncts., but in SIEG ed 1, the others are simply modifiers in phrase structure.

Comment: @BillJ The student resource webpage for the book (https://www.cambridge.org/sieg2 > View resources > Student Resources) provides the glossary, among other things. Unfortunately, the term 'adjunct' is not included in the glossary.

Comment: @brett-reynolds is the co-author of the second edition and also a regular on this site. Maybe we can get some insight into this change.

Comment: Well, can't wait to find out what Pullum will say. That being said, in The Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar they do mention that in some theories of syntax adjuncts "can operate at phrase level (e.g. *silly* in *a silly person*) as well as clause level" (s.v. adjunct). Bas Aaarts also admits that he prefers to use "the functional label Adjunct inside phrases, rather than Modifier" (Aarts 2011: 351) This is not how I use these terms but why not?

Comment: @Araucauria et al. Got a reply from GKP,. It's unsatisfactory, I've emailed him back highlighting the inconsistency in the definition of Adjunct given in GGEL/SIEG 1 and that given (or implied) in SIEG 2. I've suggested that it needs urgent attention. Will update you all when I get a further reply.

Comment: @AlexB. Well, because in CGEL and in their first edition of this book, they reserved the term  specifically for modifiers within clauses or VPs, when most people were using the term to mean *modifier*. Now that loads of people have adopted their practice, they’ve swithered  back to the original, which is confusing and doesn’t fit with CGEL. ASIEG is meant to be based on CGEL.

Comment: I was taught syntax at university shortly after 2005, and "adjuncts" were definitely not restricted only to clauses as BillJ says. I've never even heard of "supplements" before. I think the takeaway thing to learn is that even when discussing a single language, linguists don't agree on terminology.

Comment: @Araucaria et al. Got a further reply from GKP. Here's what he says:  "Okay; you convince me that there is inconsistency here, and that SIEG2 should be reworded to remove it. I hope we can do this with small changes in the second printing. I'll work on this with my collaborator Brett Reynolds, and we'll keep you in touch".

Comment: @Missedmyflight. So, the authors will reword the next printing of SIEG2. Meanwhile, rest assured that the underlined items in [12] ii-iv on p214 are not adjuncts, but simply modifiers in phrase structure.

Comment: I'm glad my small question can lead to such change. Thanks everyone for having a discussion, especially @BillJ who take your time to email GKP.

Comment: @BillJ I'm veryglad they've decided to keep it consistent with ASIEG 1 and CGEL. Good work. I do note, though,  the original choice in CGEL to use *Adjunct* as a clause-level label was kind of arbitrary. It's useful to have special names for consittuents (or supplements) at the clause/VP level, for example *Object*, *Subject* etc. The choice to use *Adjunct* for that purpose though, is just an arbitrary choice, I think. However, it *is* of paramount important to be consitent. Indeed that's one of the great strengths of CGEL!

Comment: @Araucaria-him I think you ask the same question as my original question, which still remained unanswered: Why the authors only reserve the term "adjunct" for elements in clause but not for elements in other types of phrase stureture?

Comment: @IMissedmyflight It's just because it's useful to have a name specifically for elements at clause level. The natural thing to do is take one of the two modifier labels *modifier* and *adjunct* and use one for modifiers in general and the other for modifiers at clause level. Basically, they needed a term to replace the much abused and ambiguous *adverbial* label.

Comment: @AlexB. Which latest latest one? There've been a few!

Comment: @AlexB. I have presented some important information to GKP which I think will wrap this whole mess up. I'll post an update here as soon as he has had a chance to look at it. Just hold fire for now.

Comment: @BillJ et al. I'm not sure what you are talking about but it seems like there is still disagreement on what 'adjunct' actually means in CGEL. To make the matter more complicated, I dig a little bit further and found the slide on Attribute modifiers on GKP website (http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/grammar/attrib_sli.pdf). On page 1 of the slide, you can see that GKP uses the term adjunct to include modifiers in noun phrase structures.

Comment: @AlexB. Well, that was a very clear answer, indeed. I have to say I'm an avid reader of their books (CGEL, SIEG1,2) and I had believed that adjunct is meant to only include modifiers in VP, or Clauses and supplements, partly because, as GKP said, most examples in their books are modifiers in VP or Clauses. Now that in the latest edition of SIEG, they explicitly include modifiers in AdjP, AdvP, and PP in the adjunct chapter, it shed the light on how I have misunderstood the term for the whole time.

Comment: @IMissedmyflight Be patient!

Comment: @BillJ I'll keep checking on this question from time to time. Please keep me up to date.

Comment: @AlexB. I see where you are coming from; I saw the email GKP wrote that you posted here the other day. But BillJ said he presented the authors with the evidence that might indicate otherwise so I'm waiting for their reply again to come to my own conclusion.

Comment: @IMissedmyflight Update: I sent a reminder email to GKP yesterday.

Comment: @BillJ Thanks for reminding me. Still checking on this question on a daily basis :)

Comment: @IMissedmyflight I've just received an email from GKP. He still doesn't entirely agree with what we're all saying, but he does concede that parts of _SIEG2_ need to be revised in some cases so that the term "modifier" replaces "adjunct". I imagine the authors will do that at the second printing.

Comment: @BillJ His reply seems to contradict each other, at least for me. We will have to just wait for the reprinted version of the book, then.

Comment: @IMissedmyflight I sent another email to GKP, and at last he has agreed that SIEG2 is inconsistent with _CGEL_ / _SIEG1_. In the first reprint of _SIEG2_, the word 'adjunct' will be replaced with the word 'modifier' where necessary

Comment: @BillJ So does that mean he finally agrees with us that 'adjunct' is meant to include only modifiers in VPs or clauses and supplements? Also, thanks very much for all the efforts.

Comment: @IMissedmyflight Yes, he does! It may be some time before the reprint comes out, though.

Comment: @BillJ That's a great relief, honestly.

Comment: @AlexB. Since I am not the one receiving a direct response from GKP himself like you guys, all I can do is make a conclusion based on hearsay.  Maybe I should wait for the reprinted edition and confirm the fact myself.

Comment: @BillJ I go back and read the chapter on adjunct from CGEL again and on page 665 I found that the authors, in fact, explicitly said: "the term ‘adjunct’ covers modifiers in the VP or clause together with related supplements" (by related supplements, I suppose they mean supplements with VP or clause as an anchor). So this might contradict GKP's reply to AlexB.

Comment: @IMissedmyflight No, supplements can have virtually anything as their anchor, not just VPs and clauses. See CGEL pp 1350-1361.

Comment: @BillJ I'm aware of that. But I suppose the authors use 'adjunct' to cover only supplements with VP and Clause as an anchor because they said 'related supplements' not 'supplements' in general.

Comment: @IMissedmyflight "Related supplements" means supplements of any kind that are attached to a clause, all of which H&P call adjuncts.

Comment: @BillJ I see. Thanks for clarifying the term.

Comment: I think it's important to remember that CGEL is not a religious text (so no exegesis required here), we can simply ask the authors, and if they say that's not how they intended to use the terms in question, we have to accept that. Their use may be inconsistent, it may change etc. and this is totally normal in research.

Comment: If possible Id like to know what Prof Rodney (co other of CGEL) think of this, seeing that he is the first to redefind 'adjunct' in his original work in 1984.

Comment: Why not ask him yourself, if you're so interested? He might have his own view on this, different from Pullum's  (and that's fine, too!) https://languages-cultures.uq.edu.au/profile/1061/rodney-huddleston although cf. his remark that **modifiers** are "adjuncts which share the above properties with complements" (Huddleston 1984: 224)

Comment: I did email him once but got ignored.

Comment: Also I misremembered the book in which he redefined 'adjunct.' He, in fact, dedicated the whole paragraph to defind 'adjunct' in his work in 1988 (which is basically a digest of his work in 1984).

Comment: "Adjuncts are less tightly integrated into the structure of the clause than are complements: their occurrence is less governed by grammatical rule. They are always optional and their selection does not depend on the presence of a verb of a particular subclass (these are the criteria we used to distinguish them from complements); nor can we give grammatical rules excluding particular combinations of different kinds of adjunct or imposing a maximum number of adjuncts for any clause..." (p. 65)

Comment: I see, I took a look at Huddleston 1988 (not just the quotes you shared here), everything is clear, all modifiers are adjuncts but not all adjuncts are modifiers, same as what Pullum has been saying.

Comment: Did he expand the definition of adjunct somewhere else in the book? If that is the case, then I have to agree that the authors have been consistent in using the term and we should bury the hatchet here.